# Select option by attributte of another select with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dropdown, html-select

I have 2 select boxes. One have attribute "data-typdv". I need get number from attribute from currently selected option and select the same value in second dropdown. I cant get it work in last few days. Can someone please help me, what I doing wrong? Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x1_field_skrinka").change(function() {
      var myvalue = $("#x1_field_skrinka option:selected").attr('data-typdv')),
    var n2 = document.getElementById('x1_typdv2'); n2.value = myvalue.value;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Get "data-typdv" attribute from this: <br>
<select id="box1" name="box1">
    <option value="a" data-typdv="0"></option>
    <option value="b" data-typdv="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="c" data-typdv="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="d" data-typdv="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="e" data-typdv="4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="f" data-typdv="5">Val 5</option>
    <option value="g" data-typdv="6">Val 6</option>
</select>
<br> and select value with the same number here:
<br>
<select id="box2" name="box2">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="5">Val 5</option>
    <option value="6">Val 6</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use n2.value = myvalue This will normaly work, because myvalue is already the value of the attr 'data-typdv'

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the `ID`
2. Use `$("option:selected",this)` to get selected option

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#box1").change(function() {// put the correct ID
      var myvalue = $("option:selected", this).attr('data-typdv')
    $("#box2").val(myvalue)// put the correct ID
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Get "data-typdv" attribute from this: <br>
<select id="box1" name="box1">
    <option value="a" data-typdv="0"></option>
    <option value="b" data-typdv="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="c" data-typdv="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="d" data-typdv="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="e" data-typdv="4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="f" data-typdv="5">Val 5</option>
    <option value="g" data-typdv="6">Val 6</option>
</select>
<br> and select value with the same number here:
<br>
<select id="box2" name="box2">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="5">Val 5</option>
    <option value="6">Val 6</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#box1").change(function() {
      var myvalue = $("#box1 option:selected").attr('data-typdv');
      $("#box2").val(myvalue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Get "data-typdv" attribute from this: <br>
<select id="box1" name="box1">
    <option value="a" data-typdv="0"></option>
    <option value="b" data-typdv="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="c" data-typdv="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="d" data-typdv="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="e" data-typdv="4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="f" data-typdv="5">Val 5</option>
    <option value="g" data-typdv="6">Val 6</option>
</select>
<br> and select value with the same number here:
<br>
<select id="box2" name="box2">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="5">Val 5</option>
    <option value="6">Val 6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the id **#x1_field_skrinka** to **#box1**  and remove extra ) from here `.attr('data-typdv'))`
and replace `var n2 = document.getElementById('x1_typdv2'); n2.value = myvalue.value;` with `$("#box2").val(myvalue);`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#box1").change(function() {
      var myvalue = $("#box1 option:selected").attr('data-typdv');
     $("#box2").val(myvalue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Get "data-typdv" attribute from this: <br>
<select id="box1" name="box1">
    <option value="a" data-typdv="0"></option>
    <option value="b" data-typdv="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="c" data-typdv="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="d" data-typdv="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="e" data-typdv="4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="f" data-typdv="5">Val 5</option>
    <option value="g" data-typdv="6">Val 6</option>
</select>
<br> and select value with the same number here:
<br>
<select id="box2" name="box2">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="5">Val 5</option>
    <option value="6">Val 6</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `attr()`, use JQuery [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to achieve this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#box1").change(function() {
    $("#box2").val($("option:selected", this).data('typdv'))
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Get "data-typdv" attribute from this: <br>
<select id="box1" name="box1">
<option value="a" data-typdv="0"></option>
<option value="b" data-typdv="1">Val 1</option>
<option value="c" data-typdv="2">Val 2</option>
<option value="d" data-typdv="3">Val 3</option>
<option value="e" data-typdv="4">Val 4</option>
<option value="f" data-typdv="5">Val 5</option>
<option value="g" data-typdv="6">Val 6</option>
</select>
<br> and select value with the same number here:
<br>
<select id="box2" name="box2">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">Val 1</option>
<option value="2">Val 2</option>
<option value="3">Val 3</option>
<option value="4">Val 4</option>
<option value="5">Val 5</option>
<option value="6">Val 6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain what would you to do. 
To get the selected item number in the first select field use this

`var myvalue = $("#box1 :selected").attr('data-typdv');`

There you get the number associated to the selected item.
Once you get this what would you do ?
Can you explain more??